# How to perform induction step in this question?

Tags: induction

Q:Prove By induction 
$2^{n+1} > n^2$ for all positive integers.

Step 1: 
Base case:
$n=1$, we get $4>2$

Step 2:
Induction hypothesis:
$n=k, 2^{k+1} > k^2$

Step 3:
Induction Step:

to prove:
$2^{(k+1)+1} > (k+1)^2$

Left hand side=$2^{k+1}.2$

How to proceed and prove after this step?

Comment: Did you try to expend the right side?

Comment: @wece I have no idea about how to prove by expanding the right side

Comment: Did you try to search in this site for smilar examples because there is a lot of questions of this sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $2^{k+2} > (k+1)^2$. Consider the left side
\begin{align*}
2^{k+2} & = 2^{k+1} \, . 2\\
& > k^2 \, . 2 && (\text{by induction hypothesis})\\
& = k^2+k^2\\
& > k^2 + (2k+1) && (\text{for all } k \geq 3, k^2>2k+1)\\
& = (k+1)^2.
\end{align*}
So you need to adjust your base stpes to cover the missing cases from the inequality (namely $k=1,2$).